# reducing delay on raspberry pi to arduino serial communication

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I'm currently trying to rotate a motor on my Arduino Uno through serial communication from my Raspberry Pi 3. My code itself currently works however sometimes when running the python script the motor will not turn or indicate any response. From what I've been able to find online, I feel like I'm sending signals faster than the Arduino is reading them, and I can't seem to find a way to minimize the delay and make my motor response consistent.

Here is my Arduino code:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

#define STEPS 128 

Stepper stepper(STEPS, 8, 10, 9, 11);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
if (Serial.read() == 50) {
stepper.setSpeed(8); //  rpm
stepper.step(128); // do n steps -- corresponds to one revolution in one minute
}
else if (Serial.read() == 51) {
stepper.setSpeed(8); //  rpm
stepper.step(-128); // do n steps -- corresponds to one revolution in one minute
}
}
```

Here is my Python code

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

time.sleep(1)
num="3"
ser.write(bytes(num.encode()))
```

Also I'm not sure how Arduino is reading my ser.write, as when num = 2, I see "50" in my Serial Monitor, when num = 3, "51" appears in my Serial Monitor, and so forth.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the Baud rate? That is change `9600` to `115200` on both Arduino code and the Python code. Can you check if this improves your results?

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you are opening the serial monitor while the Python program is running, it is also going to slow it down. 

Also, what is the output of "print(bytes(num.encode())" in your Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial communication is always done in Bytes. So whatever you send through your interface will be received as a sequence of Bytes. As you encoded your "3" as UTF-8 it will be sent as 0x33 (51). Your "2" is 0x32 (50) respectively.

Increasing the baudrate as suggested in a comment won't help you as it will only increase the speed data is transmitted/received. Without a measurement you won't notice a difference betweeen sending a single byte with 9600 or 115200 baud.

As long as both device operate on the same baudrate and you do not exceed the max baudrate of any device (somewhere around 2 million baud for Arduino Uno) you cannot send to fast. (given a suitable cable and distance)

You might run into problems with too long cables but that's several meters for 9600 baud even in noisy industrial environment.

Usually you wait for data to be available in the receive buffer befor you read.

```
void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.print("I received: ");
    Serial.println(incomingByte, DEC);
  }
}
```

Maybe not doing so causes some delay. I cannot tell for sure as you did not provide the length of the observed delay.

If the Arduino is already running when you execute your Python code I don't see any other issue with your code. If it is booting while you send you might observe some delay because of the Arduino bootloader. It will wait some time for possible firmware updates befor it starts the actual application code.

Answer (score 0):

Small pieces of data may sit around in the output buffer before being sent. Try using Serial.flush() after write to let the os know you want the data sent asap.